# Java ArrayList Position

Tags: java, list

I am iterating a list and getting values like.

```
Kolkata, Mumbai, Chennai, Hyderabad, Delhi.
```

I need to print like the below format. After every even number of iteration, the value should go to the next line.

```
Kolkata,Mumbai,
Chennai,Hyderabad,
Delhi
```

Comment: Kolkata.Mumbai then in the new line Chennai Hyderabad, then again in the new line Delhi

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should post your code as well.

Comment: A few more SO users should come here and they all should welcome @SourishBarman. Instead of welcoming a new SO user we should stick to the problems and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("chennai");
        list.add("kolkata");
        list.add("hyderabad");
        list.add("delhi");
        list.add("mumbai");




        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list.get(i)+",");
            if(i%2==1)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the working demo of what you wanted. Just use a counter variable to achiever your purpose.

Comment: There was no need to initialize an extra variable `k`, it can be done using `i` alone. Just replace `if (i%2 == 2)` and remove the line `k = 0` .

Comment: (i%2==1) will achieve the purpose, not (i%2==2).

Comment: and, no need to initialize variable `i` outside the loop. It only increases the life cycle which was not necessary at all!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary but I prefer using a StringBuilder to gather the whole string before print it out:

```
    java.util.List<String> list = prepareList(); // omited the list preparation code.

    int currentStringIndex = 0;
    int totalStringCount = list.size();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String eachString : list) {
        sb.append(eachString);

        // If this is not the last string.
        if (currentStringIndex != totalStringCount - 1) {
            // Append comma.
            sb.append(", ");

            // Add a new line if the next string is even indexed (i.e. current string is odd indexed)
            if (currentStringIndex % 2 == 1) {
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }

        currentStringIndex++;
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, YOU must try to put some effort in coding and show us the result of your trying so we can help you...

Consider the following code:

```
List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Chennai", "Hyderabad", "Delhi"));
for (int i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
    if ((i & 1) == 1 && i != cityList.size() - 1) { // to check number if even or odd
        System.out.println(cityList.get(i) + ", ");
    } else if (i == cityList.size() - 1) {
        System.out.print(cityList.get(i));
    } else {
        System.out.print(cityList.get(i) + ", ");
    }
}
```

*Sample Output:*

```
Kolkata, Mumbai,
Chennai, Hyderabad,
Delhi
```

---

**Update**

If you need to add number of iteration to end line, as below

```
List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList("Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Chennai", "Hyderabad", "Delhi", "zzzzzzz", "eeeeee", "wwwwwwwwww", "aaaaaaaa", "sssssssss"));
int n = 3; // Number of iteration you need
for (int i = 0, j = n -1; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
    if (i == j && i != cityList.size() - 1) {
        System.out.println(cityList.get(i) + ", ");
        j += n;
    } else if (i == cityList.size() - 1) {
        System.out.print(cityList.get(i));
    } else {
        System.out.print(cityList.get(i) + ", ");
    }
}
```

*Sample Output:*

```
Kolkata, Mumbai, Chennai,
Hyderabad, Delhi, zzzzzzz,
eeeeee, wwwwwwwwww, aaaaaaaa,
sssssssss
```